# How to avoid thousand separator in FILL-IN basic component

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl, separator, regional-settings, digit-separator

I have following piece of code in my Progress application:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE IntField AS INTEGER INITIAL 1000000 VIEW-AS FILL-IN.
```

This shows the following (mind the thousand separator):

[image]

Does anybody know how I can avoid showing the thousand separator?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer, given by [Mike Fechner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1428261/mike-fechner):

Just add a FORMAT phrase like this here:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE IntField AS INTEGER INITIAL 1000000 VIEW-AS FILL-IN FORMAT ">>>>>>>>9".
```

**Edit**

Although the mentioned answer is obviously correct, I also add here another line which means exactly the same:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE IntField  AS INTEGER FORMAT ">>>>>>>>9" INITIAL 1000000 VIEW-AS FILL-IN.
```

The difference is the location of the `FORMAT ...` part: as you see in the first answer you might think that the `FORMAT ...` part refers to the `FILL-IN` (the GUI component, also known as widget), but in fact it refers to the variable.

** Extra edit:**

One important remark: refrain from using ">>>...>" (only ">" characters) as an integer format specifier: in case the value is zero, an empty string is displayed in that case, while displaying "0" in such a case is more appropriate.

Comment: Just another question: as a format specifier you mention a list of ">", followed by a "9". Why that 9? I've been trying with a bunch of ">" characters (`FORMAT ">>>>>>>>"`) and everything seems to work fine.

Comment: With the 9 in the format a value of zero is represented as „0”. With only a set of >>> the zero will be represented as an empty string.